# Oracle Query time differences

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to select same name ,but different surname and login time stamp less than 3 minute.

For example my table is like that:

```
Name    Surname      LoginTimeStamp
-----   --------    ----------------
jane    smith         30.12.2013 10:48:50
bill    green         30.12.2013 10:49:56
jane    red           30.12.2013 10:49:00
```

Result should be:

```
Name    Surname      LoginTimeStamp
-----   --------    ----------------
jane    smith         30.12.2013 10:48:50
jane    red           30.12.2013 10:49:00
```

Comment: What is the type for LoginTimeStamp ?

Comment: LoginTimeStamp type is Date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This query will return all rows where the `Name` has more than one row with a `LoginTimeStamp` in any three-minute interval. It looks three minutes before and three minutes after.

If I haven't understood the time window correctly you can adjust the `INTERVAL` part. The `INTERVAL` value only likes integers, so if you need 1 1/2 minutes before/after use `INTERVAL '90' SECOND` - Oracle won't allow `INTERVAL '1.5' MINUTE`:

```
SELECT Name, Surname, LoginTimeStamp
FROM (
  SELECT
    Name,
    Surname,
    LoginTimeStamp,
    COUNT(*) OVER (
        PARTITION BY Name
        ORDER BY LoginTimeStamp
        RANGE BETWEEN
          INTERVAL '3' MINUTE PRECEDING AND
          INTERVAL '3' MINUTE FOLLOWING
      ) AS ThreeMinCount
  FROM myTable
)
WHERE ThreeMinCount > 1
```

Comment: @Ed Gibbs Thank you for your answer.In my question i ask also different surname.How can i do this?

Comment: @cyo - Sorry, I missed that part. This just got a lot more complicated. Ideally you could use `COUNT(DISTINCT Surname)` above instead of `COUNT(*)` but Oracle won't let you. There's a workaround [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:926516600346512818) but be advised that (a) it's pretty complicated and (b) if you use it on a very large table it will run very slowly. If I think of anything easier/faster I'll update the answer and notify you, but no promises - the workaround was posted by an absolute Oracle genius so it's probably the best/only way.

Comment: Thank you for your interest.Yes i try count(distinct surname ) but as you said oracle doesn't allow.The error is "you can not use distinct with order by.."if i find solution i will post it.

Comment: A shame this question was so badly formulated and without any prior research by the OP. Because the problem is quite interesting... I would probably use something like collecting all names with LISTAGG or a Collection and checking if it contains different names :-)